# Terminated due to Memory Pressure when using UIImageView+AFNetworking.h?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, didreceivememorywarning

I am using AFnetwroking
 UIImageView+AFNetworking.h to laod images in my imageview for UITabelviw and UICollectionview

Code i used:

```
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/lovely_roses_hq-wide.jpg"];
    NSURL *imgrl =[NSURL URLWithString:str];
    NSLog(@"ImageMB url %@",imgrl);
    [cell.profilePic setImageWithURL:imgrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]];
```

i am using this code through out the application to display image in UITableview and UICollectionview.My app is being crashed  and displaying "Terminating Due to memory pressure."

Please solve my issue.

Thanks 
RAMYA

Comment: How many images are you using at once? Are you reusing cells?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using the default sharedImageCache, you shouldn't have a memory warning from that.

```
+ (id <AFImageCache>)sharedImageCache {
    static AFImageCache *_af_defaultImageCache = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _af_defaultImageCache = [[AFImageCache alloc] init];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification * __unused notification) {
            [_af_defaultImageCache removeAllObjects];
        }];
    });

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(sharedImageCache)) ?: _af_defaultImageCache;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```

As you can see it watches for memory warnings. My guess is that you're probably adding a new imageview to your cell each time you got to populate it?

We need to see more code before we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using any sharedImageCache,and cell is not reallocating memory. it has been already created in uicollectionvew custom cell and making use of it through cell.profilepic

I created a UICollectionView flaw layout

By using asepct raito i resized the image.

```
CGSize CGSizeAspectFit(CGSize aspectRatio, CGSize boundingSize)
{
float mW = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width;
float mH = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height;
if( mH < mW )
    boundingSize.width = boundingSize.height / aspectRatio.height * aspectRatio.width;
else if( mW < mH )
    boundingSize.height = boundingSize.width / aspectRatio.width * aspectRatio.height;
return boundingSize;
}
```

calculated the size and created Cell for it . and displayed image using this code:

```
  Photo *photoData = [self.photosListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

//[cell.displayImage setImageWithURL:[photoData photoURL]];
// Here we use the new provided setImageWithURL: method to load the web image
NSLog(@"photo url %@",[photoData photoURL]);
[cell.displayImage setImageWithURL:[photoData photoURL]
                  placeholderImage:nil];
//user profile pic
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/%@",photoData.userProfilePic];
NSURL *imgrl =[NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSLog(@"Image url %@",imgrl);
[cell.userProfilePic setImageWithURL:imgrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_profilepic.png"]
```

this is my code please suggest me any possible answer to avoid memory pressure.

Thanks